# How to open a SharePoint Word document as read only via FileExplorer?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, windows-explorer, read-only, sharepoint-2010

I have Windows Explorer configured to point at a couple of directories from SharePoint:

```
https://teams/projects/myproject/ProjectDocuments
https://teams/projects/myproject/SharedDocuments
```

(Originally done by right-clicking on My Computer and using "Add Network Location".)

This is great as it gives access to SharePoint documents directly from Windows Explorer. However, there seems to be a snag: There are a lot of people working on the project and generally I need to open documents as "Read Only" to view them but not prevent others from working on them. Usually I'd do this by holding down SHIFT, right-clicking on the document and choosing "Open in Protected View". But when I do this, other project members complain that they can't edit the document.

Is there any way of opening a SharePoint document via Windows Explorer and not prevent others from editing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution - hold down SHIFT, right-click on the document and pick "Open as Read-Only".

...so it works in Read Only but not in Protected View - weird!